# Replace wire harness connector on cooktop

Tags: wiring, connectors, cooktops

I have a Jennair cooktop model number JED8430BDB. I accidentally spilt some water on the cooktop and it got into the knob assembly and fried the infinity knob switch which I’ve ordered and replaced. The only other part that now needs to be repaired/replaced is the main wire harness due to the plastic connectors being burnt. I’m unable to locate this part online, but thought that since it is just the connectors that are burnt that I could cut the burnt parts off and stick a new connector on each end. What would be the best way to do this to ensure that I have the correct wire connectors for this application?
[image]

Comment: Making sure the voltage/amp rating is same or better, and it seems that connector might be close to heat, so you need a high heat/temperature rated connector.   Unless they were nice enough to mark the voltage/amp rating on the connector or you can find in the service manual, finding the right rating might be hard.  Guessing is not good if your guess is too low.  Melting, sparks, fire might happen.

Comment: Are there any markings on the existing connectors?

Comment: I couldn’t find any identifying markings on them.